# resizing vector of pointers segfaults

Tags: c++, vector, resize, segmentation-fault

I keep hitting this weird `std::vector` behavior which I can't make any sense of.

Roughly, the code looks like

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class MyClass{
public:
  MyClass():
    v_(),
    w_(init_w())
  {};

  ~MyClass()
  {};

  std::vector<int*> init_w()
  {
    v_.resize(4096);
    return v_;
  };
private:
  std::vector<int*> w_;
  std::vector<int*> v_;
};

int main()
{
  MyClass a;
}
```

Running this gives me a bad segfault at the `resize`. If a lower value is chosen for the `resize` instead, the code might not segfault at all.

**Update:**
The problem is that, contrary to what the initializer list indicates, `w_` get initialized before `v_`. Hence, in `init_w()`, `v_` state is undefined.
Reverting the order of `v_` and `w_` in the declarations fixes the problem.

Comment: Please give a minimal, compiling example that displays the problem.

Comment: @rhalbersma I've struggled several hours to break down the code into something small and easy that fails, but didn't succeed. I'm aware of the fact that this makes it hard to find the error.

Comment: @Nico: Not hard, impossible. -1 from me I'm afraid.

Comment: @Nico: Your sample code (plus a `typedef int mytype;`, to make it compile) runs fine for me with g++ 4.2.1; valgrind didn't find any issues either. I think the relevant code is missing.

Comment: @chris I've got no idea. `mytype` is a type from a larger library I have no insight in. Might there be a problem, though?

Comment: @chris It shouldn't matter, since the vector element type is a pointer.

Comment: @Nico this makes it impossible to find the error.

Comment: @Nico: You could test whether `mytype` triggers the issue by temporarily replacing it with, say, `int`. Furthermore, looking at line 591 in your `stl_vector.h` might give some hint as to what's triggering the crash.

Comment: @cdhowie, My mind jumbled it around a bit. You're right.

Comment: An answer to [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612447/pinpointing-conditional-jump-or-move-depends-on-uninitialized-values-valgrin) might help you pinpoint the source of the segfault.

Comment: Debugging can be hard and frustrating. Make sure you have good tools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426569/why-is-debugging-better-in-an-ide

Comment: Replacing `mytype` with `char` or any other POD, this compiles and runs for me.

Comment: I updated the question and added the solution. Thanks again everyone for helping me out!

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that, contrary to what the initializer list indicates, w_ get initialized before v_

You inferred that to be the case, but in reality it is not.  The order of the list is not relevant; the order of declaration in the class is.  So, your initialization list should mimic the declaring order if you want to see how the members are *actually* being initialized.

My question to you is; why are you using a vector of pointers to begin with?  Do you realize that you need to `delete` every element in the list before your object goes out of scope or suffer a memory leak?

Comment: Indeed, it's the order of declaration. Some compilers even warn if the items are declared in another order that they are initialized. The reason why I'm working with vectors of pointers is that the library I use requires that format. In particular, the vector filling routines I call have `std::vector<entity*>` as argument.

Comment: how does this answer `answers` the question ?

Comment: @Nico: Ah, ok, just be careful with that then (that stinks, but oh well, not much you can do about it.)

Comment: @JayD: The initialization order is the problem.  `init_w()` calls `_v.resize()` before `_v` is initialized.